# Is it possible to set cookie in php from 2lvl domain to all 3 and 4lvl child subdomains?

Tags: php, http, cookies

Is it possible to set a cookie accepting 3rd and 4th child-level of a domain?

It's possible to set a cookie which includes a subdomain like

`.somedomain.com`

Im looking for a way to set a Cookie for multiple levels like

`level2.somedomain.com, level3.level2.somedomain.com, level4.level3.level2.subdomain.com`
and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/it/function.setcookie.php):

> Cookies available to a lower domain, such as 'example.com' will be available to higher subdomains, such as 'www.example.com'. Older browsers still implementing the deprecated » RFC 2109 may require a leading . to match all subdomains.

So if you set a cookie for a subdomain it will be available to its sub-subdomains too. The inverse is not possible.

Comment: Do you know the way to set cookie for all 3rd and 4th subdomains per one mask? (like `.testdomain.net` set cookie for all 3rd level subdomains)